# Improve jquery code(hide(),show())

Tags: jquery, hide, show

is there a better solution for my problem except using jquery ui "accordion" ?

My working code:

```
 $('div.BWHeadingForSection a[href~="#faq-cat-1-sub-'+globalcarriernumber+'"]').on("click", function(){
            count++;
            if(count%2==0){
                alert("clicked"+count);
                $("#faq-cat-1-sub-"+globalcarriernumber).show();
            }else{
                $("#faq-cat-1-sub-"+globalcarriernumber).hide();
            }
        });
```

Thanks...

Comment: If you tell us what the code does, what the problem is, and show us a minimal example, it would be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ maybe

Comment: showing and hiding a panel, the problem when I first load the page it show() is excecuted,but if I click on it it won't close anymore...

Comment: That seems to be an entirely different question, and leading with that question would probably be a great idea ?

Comment: @adeneo ,what are you actually thinking about my idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey if you want something fancy show hide use this

```
$('div.BWHeadingForSection a[href~="#faq-cat-1-sub-'+globalcarriernumber+'"]').on("click",    function(){
 $("#faq-cat-1-sub-"+globalcarriernumber).slideToggle();
});
```

Hope it likes you